# objc is there a way to detect if the camera focus was successful or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera

I'm manually requesting a camera focus before I'm taking a picture in my app.
I added an adjustingFocus observer to detect when the focusing has ended.
When it's done I'm capturing the photo..

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"adjustingFocus"] ){
    BOOL adjustingFocus = [ [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];

    if (!adjustingFocus) {
        [self captureStillImage];
    }
}
}
```

The question is: is there a way to know if that focus succeeded and that I have a focused cam now? I know in Android it can be done, but till now I did not find a way to do it on iOS.

Thanks anyway.